# Securing data after laptop is lost or stolen

Tags: password-management, password-cracking, permissions

We have laptops encrypted and password protected. The scenario we're struggling is if user lose or report stolen laptop. 
Disabling workstation in AD and doing the rest standard procedures does not protecting data on laptop if malicious user get's credentials as it's cashed locally and than access to Laptop. Chance is small but user may fake that laptop was stolen and use log on credentials to access data on laptop.
What would be the solution or technology to solve this problem?

Comment: Look up Computrace

Answer (score 2):

If you're using full disk encryption, and the laptop is stolen, the thief will have access to the data only as long as a) it has power and b) the screen lock does not come on.

Assuming you have a sophisticated thief that knows this, they would be the same as a bad actor in your organization.

> Chance is small but user may fake that laptop was stolen and use log on credentials to access data on laptop.

In other words, you want to verify the laptop was stolen and (possibly) remote wipe it when its security is questionable because the person who has the laptop has credentials to decrypt it.

There are several open source and for-pay projects that do this:

- [Pombo](http://sebsauvage.net/pombo/)
- [Prey](https://www.preyproject.com/)
- [LoJack for laptops](http://www.lojack.com/Laptops)

Comment: I would like to know more solutions-projects available that could be used in enterprise.

Comment: Umm.... click the links above. Prey and LoJack are both enterprise ready.

Comment: What about if laptop is offline. Mentioned solutions would not work than.

Comment: By definition, a laptop that is offline is not remote controllable or trackable. In this case, you can only rely on expired credentials. This script https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4ae0f994-e618-44e2-bb1e-1398e0f2bdb1/need-to-expire-out-all-cached-domain-logon-credentials-over-30-days-old?forum=ITCG can be modified to shorten it to 1 day (or less?) and deployed via GPO.

Comment: Or disable cached credentials entirely: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852260(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I made a wonderful trojan that is better than Prey and LoJack combined. It is enterprise-ready. It can execute scripts of arbitrary size, and streams through SSL. IT'S FREE. Do not support stupid prey/lojack!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure, that offered lojack programs are NOT the ideal solutions. 
**If you cannot write your own BIOS with your own lojack, the closest to the solution would be to use encryption with selfdestruction upon unsuccessful decryption. Even this seems to be crackable, according to news, if they are valid.**

Lojack programs secure your physical asset, and only offer trust based data security = no data security.
Example: Computrace is a wide-spread, preinstalled, mostly secretly operating and close to irremovable rootkit on most todays computers, especially laptops. 
 Yes, it is very probable, that you already have it running on your machines.

What are the problems with it?

1. It exactly acts like a rootkit, but its whitelisted, trusted and widespread. Resides in BIOS or a dedicated chip, automatically install itself to a hidden part of your hard drive, communicates with server upon any possibility. When you "upgrade" it, it can even remote wipe your hard drive. Reflashing a new updated, official (non-custom/rootkit-clean) BIOS, or wiping hard drive does not work.
2. You have no technical ensurance that the company in control does not datamine you. Law enforcement territory: US.
3. You have very few control over this program. Even deactivating it permanently does not remove it from your BIOS. It activates itself even if you never paid for it, or new about its exstence. If turned on, you can not turn it off, not even the company.
4. It is proven to be able to get altered and still whitelisted by leading antivirus programs. If it gets altered, it can practically corrupt any running software from BIOS level, approved by antivirus prgrams.

You can only buy a clean motherboard, flash custom BIOS, or buy opensource or military hardware, which come without it. Or use a nonpopular Linux distribution.
Practically lojacks are massive backdoor risks, which seems to alarm only a very few people. Most people even pay for being datamined.

If you are a company working with sensitive data, you should avoid "trust" based security. Also if you operate wth EU countries/citizens too, you must follow the new personal data protection law coming in 2018. The lack of data protection can cause you paying 4% of the companys income as a fine. Each time.

**So solution:**

*What I said, I meant it. If you can not write a custom BIOS, you need to trust someone, and hire them to do that to exclude this rootkit, or write one, which does the same, connects to your servers, and more secure than this one. Also make sure, that your state does not force you to implement a backdoor. Use self destructing, or exponentially time locked encryption, like Apple does.*